# Would adopting the veil and Rawls' two principles bring about the result Rawls' desires?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy

What problem(s) is Rawls' veil of ignorance meant to fix? Do you think the problem is a real one in contemporary America? Would adopting the veil and Rawls' two principles bring about the result Rawls' desires?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question.

Comment: Welcome! Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to tell us a bit more about your context and motivations here? What might you be reading or studying that has made Rawls' argument interesting or urgent to you? What might you have found out so far?

Comment: Closing at this time pending further development of the question

Answer (score 3):

The veil of ignorance is not meant to fix something, it describes the problem of the determination of the results of a decision. Rawls applies it to the example of people in a society who have to decide about their future social order, without knowing their own role in the future society. Rawls calls this "not knowing" the "Veil of Ignorance".

I think the problem applies to all societies, also to America. Nobody knows about all implications of any political decision. For example, the introduction of a medical health care system in America was very controversial. However, nobody in America really knows if they would possibly depend on such a system in the future.